# Removing verification scripts from a stock ROM

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, stock-rom

I'm not really familiar with Android development so I'm not sure how to go about this, sorry if those questions are basic.

I have successfully flashed a TWRP recovery on my MTK6797 phone (UMI Z Pro) and I can enter it but somehow managed to soft brick it (the ROM itself doesn't boot, - hangs on the boot screen).
So I'd like to install the stock ROM again but keep TWRP recovery since I was planning to tweak the ROM or even perhaps build a custom ROM for this phone since there are none available and probably won't be any in the future.

The problem is that the stock ROM contains some verification scripts, here's a quote from their official forum:

> You need the original boot, recovery and system image on your phone
>   since the update script checks their integrity before running. As a
>   conclusion, if you have a custom recovery on your phone and/or ever
>   rooted it, you cannot update it via FOTA but the only way is flashing
>   with SPFT.

How would I go about removing those scripts from the stock ROM? Or does anyone know of another solution to this - TWRP recovery + stock ROM on this phone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite get it, you already know how to flash TWRP, why not just go ahead and flash that stock ROM the normal way, then flash TWRP again? Side note: next time you do this, after you flashed TWRP, make a backup of the stock ROM immediately.

Comment: @AndyYan I'll try repeating it but what could've caused the soft brick?

Comment: I can't really pinpoint it, since you know what you did better...

Comment: @AndyYan That's the thing, I can't come up with why that could've happened. I know that the recovery is on a seperate disk partition from the Android partition thus completely independent of the Android system.  

I flashed TWRP 3.1.0 based on the `UMI Z.V3.01_20170116` kernel version of the stock ROM using SP Flash Tool.
The ROM version was `V3.01_20170408`. I also only flashed the recovery.

Answer (score 0):

One question first your phones a umiz pro and the twrp is based on umi z.V3.xxx.xxxxx  from Google it appears that there is a base and pro model am I correct
If so then I think from your post it sounds like u flashed the base model recovery on. A pro model I have done this on a homtom ht7 I really messed it up but I think that is your problum

Comment: They state that the recovery works for both UMI Z and UMI Z Pro although I did use a UMI Z scatter file, I'll try using the UMI Z Pro scatter file. The phones are actually identical except for a dual camera instead of a single one on the Pro.

Comment: I try to stay away from mtkxxxx had bad luck with all of the ones I had just have to be really carefully with the scatter file when I messed up my ht7 I made a hard brick of it but threw a guide and I have no idea what it was called or where to find it now but it's basically a tear down of the phone and u have to sodder a wire from one point to a nother so the computer will recognize the phone and it does now for me just having trouble flashing it now  but that's all I got sir sorry couldn't be more help